# Map Two Multi-dimensional Arrays into an Object

Tags: javascript, arrays, algorithm

I was asked in an interview to process two multidimensional arrays into one object with the format similar to:

```
{
   'sally': {
       id: 1,
       metrics: {
           sales: 6000,
           missed: 0
       }
   },
   'bob': {
       id: 2,
       metrics: {
           sales: 1000,
           missed: 0
       }
   },..
}
```

However, I was unable to figure it out. I've tried doing nested for-loops, but the problem with this is I'm worried about execution time. According to the interviewer, it should have an execution time of `O(n)` and if I understand Big O correctly, a nested for-loop would have an execution time of around `O(n^2)`. Here is the code I have so far:

```
// returns a dictionary
let testIAteShitOn = (requested_user = false, requested_metric = false) => {
  // is the array always organized the same?
  let users = [
    [1, "Sally"],
    [2, "Bob"],
    [3, "George"],
  ];

  // same here, is this always organized the same?
  //  are there only ever 2 metrics?
  let metrics = [
    [1, "sales", 5000],
    [1, "sales", 1000],
    [3, "missed", 1000],
    [2, "sales", 1000],
  ];

 for (let i = users.length - 1; i >= 0; i--) {
    let id = users[i][0];
    let data = findDiamond(id, metrics);

 }

 return obj;

}


let findDiamond = (id, array) => {
    return array.filter((item) => item[0] == id);
}
```

I would appreciate any help on this and advice on where and how to best learn algorithms, data structures, and Big O.

Comment: I'm not sure about the execution times but this sounds like a perfect example for the usage of `reduce()` https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/Reduce

Comment: How does an input array look like?

Comment: @ITgoldman sorry, it’s the users and metrics array in my code

Comment: "*convert*" - as noted in comment below, Sally has 6000 in your expected output, which is not *converting* the arrays, it's processing them.

Comment: Also, you can lookup online and read about sets and hashmaps for a conceptual background.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You could use two separate loops to get the wanted result with a helper object which has the reference to each user by the `id`.

```js
const
    users = [[1, "Sally"], [2, "Bob"], [3, "George"]],
    metrics = [[1, "sales", 5000], [1, "sales", 1000], [3, "missed", 1000], [2, "sales", 1000]],
    references = {},
    result = {};

for (const [id, name] of users) {
    references[id] = result[name] = { id, metrics: { sales: 0, missed: 0} };
}

for (const [id, metric, value] of metrics) {
    references[id].metrics[metric] += value;
}
    
console.log(result);
```

```css
.as-console-wrapper { max-height: 100% !important; top: 0; }
```

Comment: I thought that the different entries for the same users should be added, so `sally` should have `6000` metrics, does she?

Comment: @messerbill, nice catch. please see edit.

Comment: @messerbill super elegant and clean solution. Do you have any resources you can point to for me to help me solve problems like this in the future?

Comment: @G.Rose this is Nina Scholz's answer ;) generally your code will become more "clean and elegant" while your gathering more experience. Searching for "best practice xxxxx" often helps

Comment: Right! So sorry @NinaScholz wasn't paying close enough attention

Answer (score 1):

If you are unaware of the total metrics there are. You could create a set of metrics and create property in the ouptut object for each metric

```js
const users = [[1, "Sally"], [2, "Bob"], [3, "George"]],
    metrics = [[1, "sales", 5000], [1, "sales", 1000], [3, "missed", 1000], [2, "sales", 1000]],
    output = {},
    allMetrics = new Set(),
    metricMap = {}
    
for (const [id, metric, value] of metrics) {
  allMetrics.add(metric);
  metricMap[id] ??= {}
  metricMap[id][metric] ??= 0
  metricMap[id][metric] += value
}

for (const [id, name] of users) {
  output[name] = { id, metrics: {} }

  for (const m of allMetrics)
    output[name].metrics[m] = metricMap[id][m] ?? 0
}

console.log(output)
```

Comment: What operator is `??=` I've never seen that before

Comment: @G.Rose it's the [nullish assignment operator](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Logical_nullish_assignment). If the identifier is null/undefined, then it assigns given value. Else, it keeps the identifier value. `let a = null; a ??= 5` Then `a === 5`. `let a = 10; a ??= 5` Then `a === 10`

Answer (score 1):

You can do in a more functional way using `Array.reduce` and `Object.fromEntries`

```js
const users = [[1, "Sally"], [2, "Bob"], [3, "George"]];
const metrics = [[1, "sales", 5000], [1, "sales", 1000], [3, "missed", 1000], [2, "sales", 1000]]
    
const usersDictonary = Object.fromEntries(users)
const output = metrics.reduce((res, [id, key, value]) => {
  const user = usersDictonary[id]
  const existing = res[user] || {id, metrics:{sales: 0, missed: 0}}
  existing.metrics[key] = value + existing.metrics[key]
  return {
    ...res,
    [user]: existing
  }

}, {})

console.log(output)
```

Answer (score 1):

My approach would be to make several easy transformations until we reach our target state.

```js
const combine = (users, metrics, types = [...new Set(metrics.map (([_, t]) => t))]) => 
  Object .fromEntries (Object .entries (metrics .reduce (
    (a, [id, type, value]) => {a [id] .metrics [type] += value; return a}, 
    users .reduce ((a, [id, name]) => {
      a [id] = {name, metrics: Object .fromEntries (types .map (t => [t, 0]))}
      return a
    }, {})
  )) .map (([id, {name, ...rest}]) => [name, {id: Number (id), ...rest}]))

const users = [[1, "Sally"], [2, "Bob"], [3, "George"]]
const metrics = [[1, "sales", 5000], [1, "sales", 1000], [3, "missed", 1000], [2, "sales", 1000]]

console .log (combine (users, metrics))
```

```css
.as-console-wrapper {max-height: 100% !important; top: 0}
```

We can think about this as a sequence of transformations, where we see the following steps:

- Use a `reduce` call to collect `users` into an object keyed by id, including name and blank metrics:

  ```js
  {
    "1": {name: "Sally", metrics: {sales: 0, missed: 0}},
    "2": {name: "Bob", metrics: {sales: 0, missed: 0}},
    "3": {name: "George", metrics: {sales: 0, missed: 0}}
  }
  ```
- Use another `reduce` call to add the real metric data from `metrics`:

  ```js
  {
    "1": {name: "Sally", metrics: {sales: 6000, missed: 0}},
    "2": {name: "Bob", metrics: {sales: 1000, missed: 0}},
    "3": {name: "George", metrics: {sales: 0, missed: 1000}}
  }
  ```
- Turn that into array entries, with `Object .entries`:

  ```js
  [
    ["1", {name: "Sally", metrics: {sales: 6000, missed:0}}],
    ["2", {name: "Bob", metrics: {sales: 1000, missed: 0}}],
    ["3", {name: "George", metrics: {sales:0, missed: 1000}}]
  ]
  ```
- `map` these to reformat them to look more like our target format:

  ```js
  [
    ["Sally", {id: 1, metrics: {sales: 6000, missed:0}}],
    ["Bob", {id: 2, metrics: {sales: 1000, missed: 0}}],
    ["George", {id: 3, metrics: {sales:0, missed: 1000}}]
  ]
  ```
- Use `Object.fromEntries` to turn these back into an object:

  ```js
  {
    Sally: {id: 1, metrics: {sales: 6000, missed:0}},
    Bob: {id: 2, metrics: {sales: 1000, missed: 0}},
    George: {id: 3, metrics: {sales:0, missed: 1000}}
  }
  ```

We should note that `types` are extracted from the actual metrics, so we don't hard-code `sales` and `missed`.  There is a minor performance optimization that we didn't do here: the `types` parameter is just an array of Strings (`['sales', 'missed']`) but when we use it to create our metrics object, we first map it (`types .map (t => [t, 0])`), then call `Object .fromEntries` on the result.  We aren't using the original type names anywhere else, so we could do the mapping up front and only call `forEntries` on the individual items.  I doubt it would be a serious problem, but if you like, just move that mapping call to the end of the `types` definition.  (Note that we *can't* move the `fromEntries` call there, because then the records would all share the same `metrics` property by reference.

Also note that we do make the assumption that all metrics entries have a corresponding user one.  If that might fail, we'd have to do something a little more complex to avoid adding to their non-existent metrics, or do something else to report the data mismatch.  We leave that as an exercise for the reader.

Comment: I didn't mention that this should be `O(m + n)` where `m` is the number of user records, `m` the number of metric records, which (depending upon your data) is probably just `O(m)`.

Comment: Thank you for the detailed explanation! It took me a while to digest this information, but it was very helpful. Thank you

Comment: small question: the runtime complexity would be `O(m + k + n * k + k + m + n + n + n)` where `n` is number of users, `k` is number of unique metrics and `m` number of metrics..which will boil down to `O(kn)` right?

Comment: @Dean: Yes, but I've been assuming `k` is a constant, and so `O(kn)` is the same as `O(n)`.  If it's not, then that looks correct.